# How to set the value of a property in an array of objects to be in reverse?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects called thresholds :

```
thresholds: [{
                dType: "threshold",
                from: 0,
                to: 30,
                color: "#D91427"
            },
            {
                dType: "threshold",
                from: 30,
                to: 70,
                color: "#F2910A"
            },
            {
                dType: "threshold",
                from: 70,
                to: 120,
                color: "#219131"
            }
            ]
```

How do I set the `color` property of each object in reverse? 
For example , something like this ,

```
thresholds: [{
                dType: "threshold",
                from: 0,
                to: 30,
                color: "#219131"
            },
            {
                dType: "threshold",
                from: 30,
                to: 70,
                color: "#F2910A"
            },
            {
                dType: "threshold",
                from: 70,
                to: 120,
                color: "#D91427"
            }
            ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple Ariff, just loop through the `thresholds` array. Calculate the total length of the array, and loop through the half of it, swapping the `color` values of objects inside the `thresholds[]` which correspond to each other on opposite ends, for example, 1st element -- last element, 2nd element -- 2nd element from last, and so on...

Here is the code snippet. I hope it helps.

```
var thresh_len = thresholds.length-1;
for(var i = 0; i < (thresh_len/2); i++) {
    var temp = thresholds[i].color;
    thresholds[i].color = thresholds[(thresh_len - i)].color;
    thresholds[(thresh_len - i)].color = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Pass array of colors
- Refer to that array in the object
- Use the `reverse()` property of `Array` to reverse the array, so that the reference is also reversed

```js
getThresholds(colors) {
  return [{
    dType: "threshold",
    from: 0,
    to: 30,
    color: colors[0]
  },
  {
    dType: "threshold",
    from: 30,
    to: 70,
    color: colors[1]
  },
  {
    dType: "threshold",
    from: 70,
    to: 120,
    color: colors[2]
  }]
}

const colors = ["#219131", "#F2910A", "#D91427"]

thresholds : getThresholds(colors)

thresholds : getThresholds(colors.reverse())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd loop from 0 to `(len - 1) / 2` and swap each color

```js
let thresholds = [{
                dType: "threshold",
                from: 0,
                to: 30,
                color: "#D91427"
            },
            {
                dType: "threshold",
                from: 30,
                to: 70,
                color: "#F2910A"
            },
            {
                dType: "threshold",
                from: 70,
                to: 120,
                color: "#219131"
            }
            ];

function swap(obj, i, len)
{
  let temp = obj[i].color;
  obj[i].color = obj[len - 1 - i].color;
  obj[len - 1 - i].color = temp;
}

let arrayLen = thresholds.length;

for (let i = 0; i <= Math.floor((arrayLen - 1) / 2); ++i)
{
    swap(thresholds, i, arrayLen);
}

console.log(thresholds);
```